# In an Eng Compute cluster - " cannot find GOROOT directory: /usr/lib/go"

Tags: go

I am trying to use GO in an engineering cluster. I have a private workspace, say `/eng/name/go_proj/` ; how do I set the env var and the path to point to my workspace?

```
machine2045> pwd
/eng/name/go_proj/
 
machine2045> env | grep GOROOT
machine2045> which go
/usr/company_name/bin/go

machine2045> go env GOROOT
go: cannot find GOROOT directory: /usr/local/go

machine2045> go get -u github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv
go: cannot find GOROOT directory: /usr/local/go
```

I do not want to modify my `.bashrc`  if possible since that is not recommended.

Comment: You have a problem with your go installation. The `go` binary thinks it's located in `/usr/local/go`, but instead it is in `/usr/company_name/`. Most likely you have `GOROOT` set in your shell environment.

Comment: You can also verify that the GOROOT variable is not incorrectly set in the go XDG directory. Is this a current version of go, and how is it installed?

Answer (score -1):

GOROOT (if not set manually via environment variable) defaults to /usr/local/go.
(EDIT: Well, it defaults to the parent directory of where the binary was compiled, but in many cases the end user is not compiling, they are downloading a precompiled binary... The *point* is that you need to be aware that there is a default GOROOT that will need to be overridden if you're using a non-standard directory for your go binary / installation).

Think of this as the parent folder of the bin folder that houses the go binary.
Go install instructions also encourage you to install to this location.

GOPATH specifies the root of your projects (to track sources and packages for imports, etc).
Think of this as the parent folder of the src, bin, and pkg folders used in go projects.

GOROOT should not be your workspace. GOPATH should.

If you don't want to modify your .bashrc or move your go installation to /usr/local/go, you should export a GOROOT and GOPATH variable manually, maybe in a launchmyproject.sh file:

```
export GOROOT=/usr/company_name/ && export GOPATH=/eng/name/go_proj/ && cd /eng/name/go_proj/ && vim main.go
```

Comment: `GOROOT` defaults to the parent directory of the `go` binary's current directory, it is not hard-coded to `/usr/local/bin`. While you may be able to override `GOROOT` like this, it would be preferable to fix the installation in the first place since the incorrect value is being read (or not being read) from somewhere in the environment.

Comment: This is not correct. GOROOT is defaulted to the parent of the directory where go was compiled (the dir in which all.bash was run). On distros that have precompiled go packages / installations there is no reason this would be the same as the parent of the directory where the go binary is housed, especially since it's so easy to move (more so if you've downloaded a tar.gz with the precompiled bin etc.). In the OP's case, if GOROOT defaulted as you claim, there would be no issue finding GOROOT.
https://golang.org/doc/install/source

Comment: You can see [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/b8e9ec856c2b2d717ab14e85f43e00b532c4370a/src/cmd/go/internal/cfg/cfg.go#L328), if the env variable is not set (which it generally shouldn't be) and we are not using `gccgo` (which we aren't), then the first path checked for a GOROOT is the parent of the executable directory.